# How do I use 2 seperate models in 1 view in MVC

Tags: c#

I'm farely new to MVC with only going on 2 months of experience

What I would like to know is how I can use 2 models in 1 view because the current way I'm doing it is giving me this error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

These are 2 seperate models

```
namespace SwiftMLS.Data.DataModels;

public class FAQTipCategory : BaseDataModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


namespace SwiftMLS.Data.DataModels;

public class FAQTips : BaseDataModel
{
    public int? FAQTipCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual FAQTipCategory FAQTipCategory { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;    
}
```

This is my controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SwiftMLS.Data;
using SwiftMLS.Data.DataModels;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace SwiftMLS.Web.Controllers;

public class FAQController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public FAQController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _db = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        ViewData["FAQTipsDesc"] = _db.Tips.ToList();
        ViewData["FAQDescription"] = _db.Descrpt;
        List<FAQCategory> categories = await _db.Categories.Where(m => !m.IsDeleted).ToListAsync();
        return View(categories);
    }


    //FAQ
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddPost(FAQCategory category)
    {
        _db.Categories.Add(category);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddDescription(string Title, string Description, int FAQCategoryId)
    {
        FAQ faq = new FAQ
        {
            Title = Title,
            Description = Description,
            FAQCategoryId = FAQCategoryId
        };
        _db.Descrpt.Add(faq);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    //FAQTip
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddTip(FAQTipCategory tipCategory)
    {
        _db.TipsCat.Add(tipCategory);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddTipDescription(string Title, string Description, int FAQTipCategoryId)
    {
        FAQTips faqtips = new FAQTips
        {
            Title = Title,
            Description = Description,
            FAQTipCategoryId = FAQTipCategoryId
        };
        _db.Tips.Add(faqtips);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

This is how I'm calling it in the view

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "FAQTips";
    DbSet<FAQTips> Tips = ViewData["FAQTipsDesc"] as DbSet<FAQTips>;
}

@foreach (var item in ViewData["FAQTIPSDesc"] as List<FAQTipCategory>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a real view model, that contains all the things that are going to need to be available on the view (I've guessed at some of the type names):

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
     public List<FAQTip> FaqTips { get; set; }
     public List<FAQDescription> FaqDescriptions { get; set; }
     public List<FAQTipCategory > Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Views often use aggregate information from different tables in the database.  It's good to create a ViewModel that is scoped to just the web project, that contains all the data the view will need.